# Структура объекта NodeList JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, интересует как устроен объект NodeList и ему подобные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Почему он NodeList отображается как массив `childNodes: NodeList[9]`, а не так `childNodes: NodeList` и как это сделали?
2. `elem.childNodes.length` сработает геттер на этом свойстве и возможно пересчитает содержимое, но почему оно дублируется в самом объекте и прототипе?
3. И самое понятное для меня, учитывая особенности выше, почему имя прототипа такое же, как и у объекта, он наследует сам себя? Для чего так сделано и как?

Как структурно создать такой же объект? Если это возможно.

Comment: В js все объекты, даже функция, даже массив. А еще есть прототипы. Прочитай про прототипы, поймешь.

Comment: Про то что все объекты знаю, в первом вопросе условно сравнил его с массивом. Про прототипы тоже читал, но среди объектов "Животных" и "Людей" не нашел ответа на 2 и 3 вопрос.

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, предыдущий вопрос стоит удалить, раз уж написал новый

Comment: [NodeList - это интерфейс WebAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: @Grundy, на MDN в первую очередь заглянул, но любопытство эта статья не уняла.

Comment: там дальше есть ссылка на [спецификацию по таким коллекциям](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist).

Comment: Стоит отметить, что отображение зависит от браузера, например в EDGE показывается как объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) - как уже говорилось ранее, это интерфейс, реализация которого скрыта в недрах браузера. Поэтому что именно делает свойство `length` и как оно работает именно для этой коллекции: перессчитывает при каждом обращении либо где-то кэширует значение, можно узнать лишь погрузившись в исходники конкретного браузера.

---

### Что касается отображения просматриваемых объектов в консоли.

То, как именно показывает консоль, по большей части никак не регламентировано. Поэтому в разных браузерах вывод будет выглядеть по разному.

#### Если рассматривать конкретно Chrome.

---

Имя выводимое напротив **proto** можно определить использовав свойство с именем [Symbol.toStringTag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag)

Кроме того, данное свойство влияет на работу [Object.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Теперь самое интересное: для вывода как массива, консоль должна подумать, что выводит массив.

Самый простой путь: унаследоваться от класса Array

```
class MyArr extends Array{
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но можно обойтись и обычными объектами.

Непонятно чем руководствовались разработчики, но при наличии в объекте свойства `splice`, со значением в виде функции, а так же свойства `length`, консоль Chrome начинает отображать данный объект как массив:

```
var base = {
    get length(){return 0;}
    splice(){}
}
```

Будет выглять в консоли так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в развернутом виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь все готово, чтобы сделать объект очень похожий в выводе на NodeList

```js
function NL() {
  this.splice = function() {};
}

NL.prototype = {
  length: 0, // значение свойства по умолчанию
  push(el) {
    this[this.length] = el;
    this.length++;
  },
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: "NL"
};


var nl = new NL();
nl.push(10);
nl.push(20);
console.debug({
  a: nl
});
console.log(nl + '');
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(nl));
```

При выполнении сниппета в консоли Chrome можно увидеть следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что весьма похоже на картинку в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

1. Это массивоподобный объект. Т. е. объект, ключи которого порядковые числа и есть свойство `length`. Эти объект почти всамделишные массивы, поэтому и есть общие черты. Кстати, вид подсказки зависит от браузера. Кто-то любезно подскажет длину, кто-то в скобках выведет сами узлы (FF), а кто-то выведет `Object`, кто будет верно, хотя и грубо :)
2. Геттер необходим из-за того, что это, на самом деле, "живая" коллекция. Т. е. изменения в DOM, относительно узла, и происходит пересчёт.
   Правда это скорее догадка, буду рад, если знающий добавит суровых правил.
3. Имя, как уже говорилось, может быть любым, зависит от браузера. Но логично что объект можно назвать в честь конструктора.

На счёт создания похожего объект я не понял. Создаёте конструктор, объект от него и вуаля.
Правда имя для пользовательского объекта подставит только хром, лиса презрительно назовёт объект как `Object { ... }`.

P. S. Конечно, не стоит игнорировать истину в [предпоследней](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList) инстанции. Последняя инстанция [тут](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist).
Спасибо @Grundy за ссылки, без него пришлось бы гуглить :)

Comment: _На счёт создания похожего объект я не понял_: chrome выведет просто `mytype`, а не `mytype[length]`. :-) без определенных условий :)

Comment: @Grundy, т. е. как заставить консоль выводить с названием и длину? Никак, кастомный вывод только для типов, которые известны консоли. Возможно, в светлом будущем, возможно будет автоматически выводить по свойство `length`. Но это будущее. Вероятное.

Comment: не совсем никак. но я нашел только для хрома вариант :)

Comment: @Grundy, поделитесь "как", мсье!

Comment: Да собираюсь вот ответ написать :-0