# Как работает строка this.splice?

Tags: javascript, классы

Когда внутри класса(функция с конструктором) указываешь строку `this.splice = function(){}`, функция возвращает объект в ином виде, но только внешне(ИМХО). Мне знаком метод `splice` для массива и возможно он участвует где-то на низком уровне при формировании класса, но хотелось узнать, как он на самом деле воздействует на результат.

**С указанием вышеуказанного фрагмента:**
[image: С указанием вышеуказанного фрагмента]

**Без указания вышеуказанного фрагмента:**
[image: Без указания вышеуказанного фрагмента]

**Дополнение:**
Это не зависит от браузерской консоли, в Google Chrome такая штука тоже:
[image: Google Chrome console]
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Ну я могу предположить что ваш отладчик смотрит наличие методов похожих по названию на методы Array.prototype в классе, и если такой метод нашелся - визуализирует ваш объект как массив. То есть разница лишь в том, как отладчик объект показывает.

Comment: Чтобы это проверить, надо слазить в исходники пожалуй. https://github.com/firebug/firebug

Comment: Кстати, он больше не поддерживается, пора переучиваться(

Comment: @Умеренно Упоротая Утка, дело в том, что в гугле такая же фигня(дополнение вверху). Думаю, что это не фича, а как бы правило. Вот бы только найти объяснение. Такой же эффект отображения работает в jQuery.

Comment: связанный вопрос, возможно дубликат: [Структура объекта NodeList JS](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598833/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-nodelist-js/599220#599220)

Comment: _Это не зависит от браузерской консоли_ - нет, это именно **зависит** от браузерной консоли, проверь в EDGE и IE

Comment: @Grundy, почему-то я не удивлен. Да проверил и все-же зависит.

Comment: кроме того, не обязательно делать именно конструктор, важно только чтобы в объекте был такой метод, а еще, важная особенность, не указанная в вопросе - наличие свойства `length`. Думаю стоит закрыть как дубликат.

Comment: Ну вот почему бы не сделать [mcve]?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в вопросе по ссылке посмотри :-)

Comment: @Node_pro, откуда вообще появилась мысли про влияние наличия _splice_ на отображение в консоли?

Comment: @Grundy, очень просто. При наличии его, меняется внешний вид =)

Comment: @Node_pro, не совсем так, как я написал выше в комментарии, в ответе по ссылке, и в ответе написал Qwertiy - одного splice недостаточно.

Comment: Ну и самое главное: никто не может гарантировать как именно консоль отобразит тот или иной объект. Потому что это никак не стандартизировано и производители браузеров что хотят то и творят

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По наличию метода `splice` и свойства `length` консоль определяет, каким образом отображать объект. Если и то, и другое присутствует, то показывается как массив, иначе - как объект.

Чтобы отличить такой объект от настоящего массива, надо вместо `log` использовать `dir`.

```js
console.log({splice(){}, length: 9});
console.log({length: 9});
console.log({splice(){}, length: 9, test(){}});
console.log(Array(9));

console.dir({splice(){}, length: 9});
console.dir({length: 9});
console.dir({splice(){}, length: 9, test(){}});
console.dir(Array(9));
```

Для того, чтобы увидеть разницу между `log` и `dir`, консоль Хрома надо открыть **до** исполнения скрипта. В таком случае получится следующий результат:

[image: Скриншот консоли Хрома]

Comment: Вот ты нехороший человек :-) ну закрыл же как дубликат уже - там тоже самое :)

Comment: @Grundy, про dir там не вижу.

Comment: _Чтобы отличить такой объект от настоящего массива, надо вместо log использовать dir._ - не вижу в консоли разницы по выводу, по крайней мере в хроме

Comment: @Grundy, сначала открой консоль, потом запусти код, а не наоборот. Смотрю тоже в хроме.

Comment: ага, заметил. Удобочитаемый вид, такой удобочитаемый :)

Comment: @Grundy, добавил в ответ пояснение про консоль и скриншот.

Comment: Стоит еще добавить, что поведение консоли не стандартизировано, и она вообще как хочет может рисовать объекты